# What is the amount of UV light required to make fluorophores glow and what is the minimum amount of electricity needed to achieve this?

Tags: fluorescence, light

So I have heard that fluorophores glow under UV light, so I was wondering what is the minimum amount of UV light needed to make the fluorophores glow and what would be the minimum amount of electricity required to make that much amount of UV light.

Also, is there any other type of light that makes fluorophores glow but requires a lesser amount of electricity?

Comment: There is no minimum, per se, though you will encounter a limit of detection issue as you decrease the UV excitation light intensity. As for electricity, there are various electrically powered UV light sources, e.g., UV LEDs, UV fluorescent lamps, UV lasers, etc. Their efficiencies vary greatly.

Comment: @EdV Could you suggest to me a device that releases UV light and is small, light, inexpensive, and uses less electricity than an LED or at least a similar voltage to it?

Comment: What specific chromophore are you interested in? You may be able to tailor the light source specifically to the absorbance wavelength of your chromophore to reduce power consumption by the lamp.

Comment: @Andrew I don't have an exact fluorophore or chromophore, but rather a mixture of 3 fluorophores, quinine, rhodamine B and fluoroscecin.

Comment: The recording of the signal seems underappreciated, but it is part of the overall equation, too. How sensitive is your device to record the released radiation in this spectral range? Do you observe by naked eye? A human behind a microscope?  A normal (video) camera mounted on a microscope? A Peltier-cooled ICCD camera? Is the sample excitation (and thus fluorescence) continuous (say, a deuterium lamp), or a pulsed laser? For how long of exposure time may you integrate signal intensity per frame to improve the S/N ratio which would be _good enough_ (living cells _vs._ dead sample) for you?

Comment: @Buttonwood I am no genius but I can only say that it will be viewed by the naked eye and will probably be used about 7-8 hours a day. I am trying to create a type of light out of this.

Comment: @Aster17 So your interest is to harvest the fluorescent light like in a lamp, and not as a fluorescence marker in microscopy.  Well, then you (equally) search for the (photochemical) quantum yield which is a value on occasion reported ([example](https://doi.org/10.1021/je60062a002), [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/002223138290045X)) to see the ratio of photons emitted by the dye over photons injected to excite the dye.

Comment: @Buttonwood I am sorry but I am really unable to understand any of it, so if you could ease on the words a bit, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Buttonwood I am unable to the quantum yield of quinine, but the quantum yield of Rhodamine B is 0.7 and fluorescein is 0.79, but if quinine sulphate works like quinine (gives a blue glow in UV light), then its quantum yield is 0.546.

Comment: The efficiency depends on the solvent, and on the wavelength of excitation, too [like here; quinine](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003269767901741).  There are instances water (like in [tonic water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonic_water)) and a commercial black light source suffice. Yet for me, I'm afraid at present your question too much open ended.

Comment: @Buttonwood My solvent is water if you need to know. I just need a small and inexpensive source of UV light that uses less electricity than LED.

Comment: A single photon is all that is needed to cause a molecule to fluoresce or phosphoresce, and photomultipliers can detect single photons. As to the amount of electricity, there are endless possibilities, but sunlight is free.

Comment: @porphyrin But there is no sunlight in the night!

Comment: @Aster, its always sunny somewhere :)

Comment: @porphyrin But not inside a house.

Comment: It appears you are wanting to invent a white light source, with inexpensive UV excitation of blue (quinine), green (fluorescein) and red (rhodamine) fluorophores in liquid solution. It needs to work at night, and UV LEDs require operating voltages higher than you want. So this is something aimed at benefitting people who would otherwise have no light at night. Is my understanding correct? If so, I think white LEDs, with rechargeable battery power source, and something like a hand crank generator or solar cell to charge the battery, might be better.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to achieve a source of light that uses a very low amount of energy, so if there are any other types of light forms I can use that use less electricity. So anything like that would be seriously helpful.

Comment: So now you need to get real and do the numbers: low energy in means low light energy, i.e., intensity in watts, lumens or whatever, as output. If your power input is 1 watt, for example, then you will get less than 1 watt of light output. So what is the minimum light output you have as a goal? Once you have that, you can start working backwards. But you also need to be more specific: what power source(s) are potentially worth consideration?

Comment: anything that is in the middle of 100-300 milli-amps as input would be good. As for how much I want to get, I can fix that by adding more fluorophores if they are falling low. As for output, the amount an LED light gives is good enough for me.

Comment: So it appears that a white light LED flashlight (aka “torch”) is all that is needed. I have half a dozen or so of them. They are relatively inexpensive, use 3 or 4 1.5 V batteries, use individual white discrete LEDs or COB LEDs (those yellow things). You can also buy inexpensive UV LED flashlights, if you really want to use a liquid solution of fluorophores and excite with UV light. All I can really suggest is experimenting and seeing what works best. As for the current, 200 mA times 4.5 V is 0.9 W, which is low power and easily achievable: even a USB port can do that.

Comment: How long do those UV flashlights last and can I use AC current for them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123058/discussion-between-ed-v-and-aster17).

Comment: I'd like everyone to remember that comments are not intended for extensive discussions. Please use chat rooms instead and please be aware that comments will be deleted.